# Treat parentheses as mathematical operator in js

Tags: javascript

How can I make javascript eval to treat parentheses as it was meant for mathematical expression?

This code, for eg:

```
var a="(";
var b=")";
alert(eval(a+2+3+b))// returns 23 while I want to get an output of 5
```

Comment: I got that and that is the problem...

Comment: You just asked this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660186/eval-to-treat-parentheses-as-the-mathematical-operator'

Comment: Yes and it was on hold and I could not wait...

Comment: Wait for what? Don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: That other question got downvoted to oblivion for no good reason. This question deserved an answer.

Comment: Those kind of questions amaze me everytime. How is OP not able to figure this out himself. Instead of putting the tiniest effort in solving it himself he double posts this question an hour later.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Thanks a lot for your concern but rather than complaining about the small thing...Please go and look back. The question is ON HOLD and I have to for a long time to get an answer, and since it is on hold, nobody will look at that question. So why don't you take that fact on your brain and stop complaining about small things.

Comment: @Amberlamps: TINIEST is the matter of perspective.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades You could try to build the string to be evaluated to an array, character by character, and then create a string with `join()` for `eval` argument.

Comment: That is actually  nice suggestion Teemu.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: Don't post duplicate questions. Your little issues are not nearly so important as you may think.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: For no good reason? You didn't bother examining the revision history before posting your comment, did you.

Comment: @CrazyTrain : See the views of that question. Still that question is in hold...How soon do you think I would have gotten the answer if I had relied solely there? I know my issues are not so important but so is yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That expression `a+2+3+b` is evaluated before `eval` is called. You are literally calling:

```
alert(eval("(23)"));
```

It you want the `+` to be passed to eval, it needs to be part of the string passed to eval as well:

```
alert(eval(2+"+"+3)); // 5
```

As for your question:

> How can I make javascript eval to treat parentheses as it was meant for mathematical expression?

You don't need to do anything. The subexpression in parenthesis must be fully evaluated before it's value can be used in the whole expression, so anything in parenthesis will be evaluated first. EX. (just like you would expect from algebraic order of operators):

```
2*(0+3) // 6
2* 0+3  // 3
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know, maybe putting in an actual arithmetic operator could help...

```
var a="(";
var b=")";
alert(eval(a+2+"+"+3+b));
```

Here's what's happening though:

`a` is a string, and the `+` operator on a string converts the added value to a string too and so on.

So you either do `a+(2+3)+b` or `a+2+"+"+3+b` to have an actual addition going on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, how you get the original string, but you could build up it into an array, character by character, and then create a string from the array. The below snippet is just a simplified example.

```
var a = '(',
    b = ')',
    stringToEval = [a, 2, '+', 3, b].join('');
alert(eval(stringToEval)); // alerts 5
```

You can also use `concat`:

```
stringToEval = ''.concat(a, 2, '+', 3, b);
```

But I think using an array would be more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

`eval` takes a string and will evaluate it as javascript. In your example the string that ends up getting parsed is `(23)` instead of `(2+3)`. What you need to do to get the eval to work correctly is something like:

```
var a = "(";
var b = ")";
var c = "2+3";
alert(eval(a+c+b));
```

Which simplifies to:

```
alert(eval("(2+3)"));
```